# Call a method from another model in Odoo 8

Tags: python, methods, code-generation, odoo-8

I'm creating a custom model in ir_model **"x_custom_model"** with its own custom fields "x_field_name" in ir_model_fields.
Meanwhile I'm also generating a view, which uses this model and those fields.
In this view I'm generating a Button which when clicked, has to call a method **"my_method"** in an already existing model **"my_model_name"**.

I'm trying to access this method while currently working in "x_custom_model".
The problem exists in not getting the method called. Any help or tips would be appreciated

1) I've tried giving the method name as a value of the name attribute as:

```
#Button attributes
<button name="my_method" type="object"/>

Error: x_custom_model had no attribute called "my_method"
```

2) Via server actions (Call_My_Method):
Settings -> Actions -> Server Actions.

- Action Name: Call_My_Method.
- Base Model: x_custom_model.
- Action to Do: Execute Python code.

Python code:

```
print "Am I getting here?"
action = {"my_model_name".my_method}

#Button attributes
<button name="Call_My_Method" type="action"/>
```

Nothing happens, not even the print.

I'm currently stuck on this issue and I don't seem to find much useful information about it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default,

```
<button name="my_method" type="object"/>
```

will call the `my_method` in the current object of the form view. You defined your object for form view like

```
<field name="model">x.custom.model</field>
```

You cannot simply call the other object `my_method` from the current button. You need to define a custom method in your current `x_custom_model` object and let it call the other object method by creating instance to that object.

Eg:

```
self.pool.get('other.object').my_method(cr, uid, arg, context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I've solved it using the server actions. I had to define the <button name="Call_My_Method" type="action" /> to the id of the server action instead of the name 'Call_My_method' i've used in my example.